# Nested attributes / form: Unpermitted params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters, nested-forms, nested-attributes

I've been going over the [active record nested attributes docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) and [strong params docs](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html) but must be missing something as my logs tell me that ownership, and image are still not being permitted:

```
User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
    Unpermitted parameters: ownership, image
```

My nested form_for with 3 models:

```
= form_for @murals do |f|

  = f.fields_for @ownerships do |owner|
    = owner.label "Artist"
    = owner.collection_select(:user_id, User.where(artist: true), :id, :first_name, { include_blank: "Pick an artist" })

  = f.hidden_field :latitude, id: 'lat'
  = f.hidden_field :longitude, id: 'long'

  = f.fields_for @images do |image|
    = image.label :file, 'Add Image'
    = image.file_field :file
    = image.file_field :file_cache, class: 'hidden'

  =f.submit 'Upload Mural', class: 'btn btn-primary upload-btn'
```

My controller (which I've also just tried with a single x`_attributes: [:xyz]` with no luck)

```
def create
    @image = current_user.murals.build(mural_params)
    if @image.save
      redirect_to :root
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  private

    def mural_params
      params.require(:mural).permit(:longitude, :latitude,
                                    image_attributes: [:file, :file_cache ], 
                                    ownership_attributes: [:user_id]
                                   )
    end
```

Image.rb:

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :mural

  mount_uploader :image, MuralUploader
end
```

Ownership.rb

```
class Ownership < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :mural
end
```

User.rb:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :authentications, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :images
  has_many :ownerships
  has_many :murals, through: :ownerships

  validates :first_name, presence: true

  mount_uploader :avatar, AvatarUploader
end
```

Mural.rb:

```
class Mural < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :ownerships
  has_many :images
  has_many :users, through: :ownership
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :ownerships, :images
end
```

Comment: Can you share your model code?

Comment: looks like your ownerships association is has_many, If that is the case, use ````ownerships_attributes: [:user_id]````

Comment: @tyamagu2 added 'em.

Comment: @mintuhouse no luck with pluralizing them.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable nested attributes updating using  `accepts_nested_attributes_for`.

```
class Mural < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :images, :ownerships
  ...
end
```

See http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html for more details.

Comment: Had that, and still no luck with getting them permitted.